# Why should i use cache and order in sequence in oracle?

Tags: oracle, caching, sequence, cycle

I am new to Database . I have been reading about sequences in oracle. I came to know about the order clause in sequence .I should quote the paragraph

> Specify ORDER to guarantee that sequence numbers are generated in order of request. This clause is useful if you are using the sequence numbers as timestamps. Guaranteeing order is usually not important for sequences used to generate primary keys.
>
> ORDER is necessary only to guarantee ordered generation if you are using Oracle Database with Real Application Clusters. If you are using exclusive mode, sequence numbers are always generated in order

I did not understand any of this . Link to the site is
[a link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/statements_6014.htm)!
Can anybody help me out ?
Pardon for any grammatical mistakes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ORDER` clause in sequence is only meaningful in **RAC**.

It guarntees the generation of sequence in order, no matter which instance received the request.

If you dont use `ORDER` then to illustrate, assume a sequence defined with `cache=20`. Instance 1 has sequence values 1 through 20 in its cache. Instance 2 has sequence values 21 through 40 in its cache.  Normally, concurrent sessions might generate sequence values in this order: 1, 2, 21, 3, 22, 4, 23, and 24.but with `ORDER` clause this values will be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,..

Hence, It is mentioned in the document that if the purpose of the sequence is to generate unique values then `ORDER` is not needed but it is needed if sequence is used to define chronological order in RAC.

**Cache:** If you specify the Cache in sequence as 20 then oracle takes 20 value in a bunch and put its value in `SGA` and data dictionary is updated once. So if you want to use 35 sequence values then there will be only 2 times when data dictionary is updated improving the performance against 35 updates in the data dictionary in case of `NO CACHE`. The cache is used to improve the performance of the sequence. But also in database shutdown, you will lose unused buffered sequence values.

Hope, It will be useful.

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks for reply !! but can you explain "received the request " in your answer and also instances and concurrent sessions ?

Comment: RAC has more than 1 instance which handles the request to the db. Means request to generate sequence may be served by any of the instance. Concurrent sessions are as name suggest multiple sessions at the same time and request from this session may be served by different instance. You must refer oracle documentation to know more about RAC

Comment: and what's with the cache ? and when should i use it ?

Comment: Ok, Updated the answer with details of `cache`

Answer (score 2):

Sequences as used to guarantee that each record gets a unique value. If you specify the ORDER property, then it also guarantees that a record created at an earlier point in time will have a lower sequence number than one created later. 
In most cases, ORDER is not required.